# Is Classical Logic the proper model of the deductive logic of human reasoning?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic, symbolic-logic

> Which mathematicians and philosophers unambiguously claimed that Classical Logic was the proper model of the deductive logic of human reasoning, and when did they say it?

The expression "Classical Logic" should be understood here as referring to the part of **mathematical logic** that assumes a bi-valuation True/False of propositions, the Law of Identity, the Law of Excluded Middle, and the Law of Non-Contradiction.

Comment: The concept of "classical logic" is a *modern* one; it was identified with the development of first non-classical ones, like [Intuitionistic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionistic-logic-development/)

Comment: Maybe Aristotle: *Pr.An*, Book I: 24a10-24a15 "First we must state the subject of the enquiry and what it is about: the subject is *demonstration*, and it is about demonstrative understanding. Next we must determine what a proposition is, what a term is, and what a deduction is (and what sort of deduction is perfect and what imperfect); and after that, what it is for one thing to be or not be in another as a whole, and what we mean by being predicated of every or of no."

Comment: See also *Post.An*, Book I: 71a1-71a11 "All teaching and all intellectual learning come about from already existing knowledge. This is evident if we consider it in every case; for the mathematical sciences are acquired in this fashion, and so is each of the other arts. And similarly too with arguments—both deductive and inductive arguments proceed in this way; for both produce their teaching through what we are already aware of, the former getting their premisses as from men who grasp them, the latter proving the universal through the particular’s being clear."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry, I meant *mathematical* Classical Logic, not Aristotelian logic. As you said yourself, the notion of Classical Logic is a recent one.

Comment: Also [Leibniz is relevant](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz-logic-influence/): unfortunately, most of his logical works was unpublished and left unnoticed until rediscovery by Russell and Couturat.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, Boole no doubt thought he had a proper model, and Frege most probably too, but Boole isn't really *unambiguous*. All a bit fluffy, that.

Comment: I would say yes to the question. But the idea is not to assume the 'bi-valuation True/False'. It has to be established.  .

Comment: You have to specify what you mean by "the proper model of the deductive logic of human reasoning". If you mean a model for how humans actually make deductions, then the answer is no, because many humans make logical errors. If you mean something else you have to clarify what exactly.

Comment: @Eliran 1. Wrong deduction is not deduction. So, no, I don't need to specify anything. It is as clear as could be and if you don't understand as is, don't answer..

Comment: It doesn't even have to be "wrong", it can be informal. And if informal deductions are not allowed then what you are asking for is not a model of human reasoning. Maybe there is no "unambiguous" claim of this sort because Boole et al. distinguished between a model and a normative framework. Peirce talked of the difference explicitly in many places. If "model of the deductive logic of human reasoning" means claiming that human reasoning is deductive and is according to classical logic, then nobody thought that. Not even that it "should" be that without qualifications.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry, your comment is irrelevant. I didn't say informal deductions were not deductions. And my question isn't about any notion of a "model of human reasoning". As to your last conclusion, I am at a loss to explain how you could possibly get there from what my question. This isn't even a question of being ambiguous. The expression "*the deductive logic of human reasoning*" just doesn't imply in any way the conclusion you suggest.

Comment: Did you forget the *model* (of the deductive logic of human reasoning)? At this point you should consider that your judgment of what is or is not clear (to others, and I do not mean myself) is flawed, and make it clearer just in case.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry, you are not making sense. If you cannot be bothered to articulate your point, I won't try to read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

*Ref to the question into the body of the post (non consistent with the title)*:

> Which mathematicians and philosophers unambiguously claimed that Classical Logic [as referring to mathematical logic] was the proper model of the deductive logic of human reasoning, and when did they say it?

Modern sources for "mathematical logic":

- George Boole, [The Mathematical Analysis of Logic (1847)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/#MathAnalLogi1847), *Introduction*, regarding the connection of Logic with Language and mind and the foundation of logical laws "upon the laws of the mental processes which they represent", as well as *The Laws of Thought* (1854), §1:

> The design of the following treatise is to investigate the fundamental laws of those operations of the mind by which reasoning is performed; to give expression to them in the symbolical language of a Calculus, and upon this foundation to establish the science of Logic and construct its method; to make that method itself the basis of a general method for the application of the mathematical doctrine of Probabilities; and, finally, to collect from the various elements of truth brought to view in the course of these inquiries some probable intimations concerning the nature and constitution of the human mind.

- Gottlob Frege, [Begriffsschrift (1879)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/#BasFreTerLogPreCal), §13:

> We have already introduced a number of fundamental principles of thought in the first chapter [the "truth table-like definition of logical connectives: *conditional* and *negation*, as well as the *generality*] in order to transform them into rules for the use of our signs [the *Ideography*].

- W&R's [Principia Methematica (1910-13)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/), *Introduction*:

> THE mathematical logic which occupies Part I of the present work has been constructed under the guidance of three different purposes. In the first place, it aims at effecting the greatest possible analysis of the ideas with which it deals and of the processes by which it conducts demonstrations, and at diminishing to the utmost the number of the undefined ideas and undemonstrated propositions (called respectively primitive ideas and primitive propositions) from which it starts.

See page 13 for the symbolic expressions of *law of excluded middle* and *law of contradiction* and page 22 for the *law of identity*.

See page 6 for the truth-functional definition of tyhe basic "logical functions" (the connectives) and page 7 for the truth-values:

> The " truth-value " of a proposition is truth if it is true, and falsehood if it is false. It will be observed that the truth-values of [compound propositions] depend only upon those of **p** and **q**$, namely the truth-value of "**p v q**" is truth if ,the truth-value of either **p** or **q** is truth, and is falsehood otherwise ; [...] that of "**~ p**" is the opposite of that of **p**; [...]

---

More details (regarding also Leibniz, Kant, Peirce, etc) into the first chapters of: Leila Haaparanta (editor), [The Development of Modern Logic (Oxford UP, 2009)](https://books.google.it/books?id=0jXavKsArnIC&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score -2):

Most people when they think of mathematics, think of numbers:

> 0,1,2,3,4,5 ...

Whereas mathematicians themselves will say there is many more numbers than this - like angles, like fractions, like the reals, like the quaternions, like the sedonions; and thatt, moreover, one can see families of numbers as number - like the categories Ab, Grp, Ring, Mod and so on.

One can see from this, that the natural numbers (0,1,2,3,4,...) are a very small part of the realm of Number, per se (though an important part).

Likewise, classical logic is merely the first staging post of what constitutes human reasoning, and a very small fraction, at that (though again, an important fraction).

Comment: Possibly true but absolutely irrelevant to my question.Further, I am not talking about classical logic. I wrote "Classical Logic".

Comment: @speakpigeon: Its true and relevant; whether you don't happen to like it now, is a metter for you and your personal conscience.

Comment: Read the question again. Your answer is absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: @speakpigeon: You might find it irrelevant - thats up to you. Nevertheless, the answer is spot-on and will work for other people who may care to look at your question.